# Set ViewBag from ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The site I am creating custom colors that can be set by the user (only on certain pages). I want to grab that data within an ActionFilterAttribute and set it in the ViewBag so I can then get the data in my _Layout.cshtml.

Here is my ActionFilterAttribute...

```
public class PopulateColorOptionsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly OptionsDataHelper optionsDataHelper;

    public PopulateOptionsAttribute(OptionsDataHelper optionsDataHelper)
    {
        this.optionsDataHelper = optionsDataHelper;
    }

    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);

        // Get the cemetery data and set it on the view bag.
        var personId = Convert.ToInt32(context.RouteData.Values["personId"]);
        context.Controller.ViewBag.OptionsData = await optionsDataHelper.GetValueAsync(personId, CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I receive an error on ViewBag that states:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ViewBag' and no extension method 'ViewBag' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [dnx451]

I'm pretty sure I'm not understanding something correctly about Filters and I would appreciate guidance on how to achieve what I am looking to do.

Comment: I am just curious @JasCav, did my answer help?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`ActionExecutingContext.Controller` is declared of type `Object` since the framework doesn't impose any restriction on which classes can be controllers.

If you are always creating your controllers inheriting from the base `Controller` class, then you can use that assumption in your filter and cast `context.Controller` as `Controller`:

```
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);

    var controller = context.Controller as Controller;
    if (controller == null) return;
    controller.ViewBag.Message = "Foo message";    
}
```

If you cannot make that assumption, then you can use a similar approach inspecting the result in the context:

```
public override async Task OnResultExecutionAsync(ResultExecutingContext context, ResultExecutionDelegate next)
{
    var viewResult = context.Result as ViewResult; //Check also for PartialViewResult and ViewComponentResult
    if (viewResult == null) return;
    dynamic viewBag = new DynamicViewData(() => viewResult.ViewData);
    viewBag.Message = "Foo message";

    await base.OnResultExecutionAsync(context, next);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast the context.Controller as Controller

Try to change the following line

```
context.Controller.ViewBag.OptionsData = await optionsDataHelper.GetValueAsync(personId, CancellationToken.None);
```

to

```
((Controller)(context.Controller)).ViewBag.OptionsData = await optionsDataHelper.GetValueAsync(personId, CancellationToken.None);
```